# HTML, set select option value to the current value of an input box

Tags: html, select

I have a select input with an option called "custom". So when the user selects "custom" from the list the value needs to be that of a corresponding text input box.

```
    <select id="choice" >
          <option value="">custom</option>
          <option value="1">A</option>
          <option value="2">B</option>
    </select> 

    <input  id="custom_choice" />
```

The "custom" text doesn't need to change, just the value for when the data from the form is collected.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: OK. So what have you done to try and solve your problem? Sounds like something you'd want JavaScript for.

Comment: Do you want the text being displayed inside the select changes to the value of the input when the selection occours? Or do you want to send the input value when the custom option is checked when submiting the form?

Comment: No i'm not looking to change the text, just the value. So the value of the custom option will be the same as the value of the input box when the form is submitted.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript would work best for this, something like this:

Bear in mind these would be two separate files:

```
var choice = document.getElementById("choice");

var custom_choice = document.getElementById("custom_choice").innerHTML = choice;
```

I think this may work but you would have to check it.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go,

**HTML**

```
 <select id="choice" onChange="javaScript:getIt(this)">
      <option value="">custom</option>
      <option value="1">A</option>
      <option value="2">B</option>
</select> 

<input  id="custom_choice" />
```

**JavaScript**

```
getIt = function(obj) {
    var val = document.getElementById("choice").value;
    //If you want to get value then user above line.
    var innerhtml =  obj.options[obj.selectedIndex].text;
    document.getElementById("custom_choice").value = innerhtml;

}
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/3u9wnba9/7/)